# How to Create Drop Down Selector in Android with Display Value and Hidden Value

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I need to create a drop down selector in an app I'm creating. The data will be sourced from web services, and will contain a display value (for users) and a back-end ID value (for further web services requests). I can't quite seem to find exactly how to accomplish this. Has this been asked before and I'm not finding it? Or does anyone know of a good resource that explains exactly how to do this? I will need to be able to capture the selection so I can use the choice in other functions.

I saw some reference to the ListPopupWindow object, but I couldn't quite figure out how to properly implement it, or if it was relevant to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: pretty easy(asked many times) ... make `public class Item { public Object ID; public String Name; public String toString() { return Name; } }` ...  get `List<Item>` from web ... create new instance of `ArrayAdapter<Item>` with this list then use adapter with ListPopupWindow/Spinner (it is important to override toString of Item class to use `ArrayAdapter<Item>` directly(without extending)

Comment: Thank you. This sounds more obvious than a lot of what I saw. I'll give it a try.